# how to use ef migration to create database?

Tags: entity-framework, migration, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I googled migration tutorials. In all af them, first run the application to create database by ef, then enable migration! Is there a way to create database with migration? not with runing the application? I try these:

```
Add-Migration CustomName // not works

Add-Migration $InitialDatabase // not works

Add-Migration InitialDatabase // not works

Add-Migration InitialCreate // not works

Update-Database // not works

Update-Database Update-Database –TargetMigration:$InitialDatabase // not works
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Initial Entity Framework Migrations Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097696/getting-initial-entity-framework-migrations-script)

Comment: What do you mean by *not works*?

Answer (score 1):

If you have everything correctly setup (connection string, having run enable-migrations) then you should be able to run `update-database` at the package manager console to get the database created.

The `$InitialDatabase` is a special migration step that's automatically created. You should never try to add a new migration step with that name.